# Share a Post on behalf of some-other user

Tags: chatter, shared-activities

I am having requirement to share a Post on behalf of some-other user(Integration User), I am trying to acheive this through `Apex Connect Api`. 
But post is shared using the logged in user.

[image]

I Refered below link code for Apex Connect Api method.[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_share_feed_element_comment.htm)

Please suggest on how to share a Post on behalf of other user.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce doesn't allow to post on behalf of other user. It could break the security.

Better, leverage  [Delegated Administration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&type=0), login with other user and post on behalf of the user.

> Delegated administrators can:

- Create and edit users in specified roles and all subordinate roles. User editing tasks include resetting passwords, setting quotas, creating default opportunity teams, and creating personal groups for those users.
- Unlock users.
- Assign users to specified profiles.
- Assign or remove permission sets for users in their delegated groups.
- Create public groups and manage membership in specified public groups.
- **Log in as a user who has granted login access to the administrator.**
- Manage custom objects and customize nearly every aspect of a custom object. However, a delegated admin can’t create or modify relationships on the object or set org-wide sharing defaults.
- Administer users across all delegated groups to which the delegated admin is assigned. For example, Sam Smith is specified as a delegated administrator in two delegated groups, Group A and Group B. Sam can assign a permission set or public group from Group A to users in Group B.

I have given an approach that can be done from UI.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post by Doug Ayers](https://douglascayers.com/2017/01/15/chatter-bot-for-feeds/), you can insert a FeedItem object and specify a CreatedById.

```
FeedItem item = new FeedItem(
parentId = UserInfo.getUserId(), // where to post message
createdById = '005j000000Bz31U', // author to impersonate
body = '<p><b>FeedItem</b> supports <i>rich text</i> but not @ mentions:</p> @[0F9j00000008TNc] @0F9j00000008TNc {0F9j00000008TNc} @{0F9j00000008TNc}',
isRichText = true
);

insert item;
```

The caveat is that you can't do @ mentions. If you need that, you've got to combine the insert and then use the ConnectAPI to set the @ mentions.